# How Scheduler is called in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

In operating system the scheduler is invoked after the system call api or after a hardware interrupt processing.

I am unable to get and found how and who calls the scheduler???

Comment: Could be duplicate previous SO question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525905/how-does-scheduleswitch-to-functions-from-linux-kernel-actually-work)

Comment: No its different there it is case of context switching but i am asking about how the scheduler is invoked is there some kernel thread is monitoring the queue or some periodic interrupt to check the running queue

Answer (score 4):

The scheduler is invoked:

1. With explicit blocking: mutex, semaphore, waitqueue, etc.
2. If `TIF_NEED_RESCHED` flag is set, on the nearest possible occasion:

   - If the kernel is preemptible:

     - in syscall or exception context, at the next outmost `preempt_enable()`
     - in IRQ context, return from interrupt-handler to preemptible context
   - If the kernel is not preemptible:

     - `cond_resched()` call
     - explicit `schedule()` call
     - return from syscall or exception to user-space
     - return from interrupt-handler to user-space

Comment: Can you suggest me where am I able to find the source code in kernel tree

Comment: @Pawan, The `schedule()` can be found in `kernel/sched/core.c`. See note before `__schedule()` to see when `__schedule()` get called. Here also `scheduler_tick()` function, which important. It calls `task_tick()` on current scheduler, which in turn sets `TIF_NEED_RESCHED` flag.

Comment: I was going through the code in /arch/avr32/kernel/entry-avr32b.S in syscall_exit_work: and several exit code they are calling schedule() function. Is this can be the right place from where after system call api and after the interrupt processing the scheduler is being called.

Answer (score 2):

The scheduler will be  invoked if the current thread/process is going to sleep/wait for some event/resource to be released.

In one of the cases of worker threads which executes the bottom half in the form of workqueues, it will run in a while loop and check if the workqueue list is empty. If found empty it will mark itself as `TASK_INTERRUPTABLE`, calls `schedule()` and then goes to sleep.

If the workqueque list is not empty the worker thread marks itself `RUNNING` and executes the deferred bottom halfs.

So in general `schedule()` is called by a task which wants to sleep and thus hands over the cpu to other processes/tasks.

Answer (score -1):

I think in case of round robin algorithm followed for scheduling some process some timer is being programmed based on time slice value which is going to invoke scheduler after that time slice gets over using interrupt functionality. and that preempt the current executing thread save its context and process ready queue figure out which thread to run next restore its context from thread stack and set PC value based on new thread's previous preempt value now new thread starts running. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_interval_timer