# Which contexts need to be saved in x86-64 with a c function return?

Tags: c, x86-64, avx, abi, context-switch

I'm writing a toy os, I know that when switching a thread, we need to save the thread's context so that the application can not feel the occurrence of thread switching. This includes all the xmm, ymm, zmm registers, it is so heavy.

But in one case, the thread switch happens to be the return of a c function, for example the thrd_yield(), according to x86 calling conventions, the callee C function don't need to save xmm, ymm, zmm. if the implementation of thrd_yield() doesn't use xmm, ymm, zmm either, we don't need to save these.

What I want to ask is, under the circumstances, which regs do I need to save? All I can think of is:

1. regs that the thrd_yield() used
2. callee-save regs thrd_yield() not used
3. rflags register(other threads maybe not a c program, maybe it doesn't follow the C language call convention, like changing direct flag.)
4. MXCSR register

Assume that I'm using the System V ABI, are there any other registers needed to save and how to save? Can you give me some advice? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your context-switch function looks like a normal function call to its callers (which just eventually returns much later), then C compiler generated code that call it will Just Work as long as the function itself saves the call-preserved registers from its caller's context, and restores those regs from the new context.  So it looks to the caller like a function-call that follows the standard calling convention.

For x86-64 System V, that's only RSP, RBP, RBX, and R12-R15.
Everything else is call clobbered, like RFLAGS, all the vector regs, AVX-512 mask regs, and x87 st0..7.

The status bits in MXCSR are also basically call-clobbered, but if you want different threads to have different FP environments (e.g. rounding mode and FTZ/DAZ), then you *do* need to save/restore that.  Same for the x87 control register, maybe not the status register.

MPX is deprecated now so you probably don't need to worry about `bnd0-3`.  If you want to have per-task performance-counter stuff, you could save/restore the PMU performance counters like Linux does of PAPI / perf.

Thread-local storage using `fsbase` or `gsbase` should be saved/restored if your OS or user-space uses it.  There are MSRs for the segment bases (so you can leave the actual segment register values as 0, the null selector).  Or if you enable it (for use in user-space or kernel) on a CPU that supports it, [`rdfsbase` / `wrfsbase`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdfsbase:rdgsbase) can copy the segment base to/from an integer register even more easily and efficiently than `rdmsr` / `wrmsr`.  (x86-64 SysV uses FS for thread-local storage.)

---

An asm caller should treat `call thrd_yield` exactly like a call to a compiler-generated function, assuming it clobbers all call-clobbered registers, leaving others unmodified.

For RFLAGS specifically, the x86-64 SysV ABI also requires DF=0 before a call, and guarantees DF=0 after it returns.  You could make `thrd_yield` run a `cld` instruction to support sloppy callers.

It's normal for everything to leave AC=0, don't fault on misaligned loads/stores.  If you want some tasks to be able to set it without corrupting each other, then you'll have to save/restore the AC bit in RFLAGS.  You might as well save/restore the whole RFLAGS since there's no harm in saving/restoring other stuff along with it.

---

Of course, if this `thrd_yield()` function is ever called from an interrupt handler that might run when user-space has valuable state everywhere (pre-emptive multi-tasking), that's a whole different ball-game.

The way Linux manages it is roughly:

- Entering the kernel in the first place saves state of integer registers, on a per-thread kernel stack.  This will be restored later when returning to user-space for this task, potentially between any two instructions so it's safe for async interrupts.
- The vector regs aren't used by kernel code (unless it calls `kernel_fpu_begin()` first).  So the interrupt and system call entry points don't have to run `xsave`; that can be deferred until switching to a new user-space task.  At which point you do `xsave` (or `xsaveopt` or whatever) for the old context, then `xrstor` to load the new after switching to the new task's kernel stack.
- Calling `switch_to` (see *[How does schedule()+switch_to() functions from linux kernel actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525905/how-does-scheduleswitch-to-functions-from-linux-kernel-actually-work)*) just switches call-preserved integer registers (of the kernel state of the caller), and saves/restores the user-space FP/SIMD state from the vector regs.  (Older kernels used to try to defer this, but modern user-space uses `movaps` all the time for memcpy and stuff.)
- When that new kernel state eventually returns back to the syscall or interrupt entry point that got that task into the kernel, the user-space state will be restored.  The call-preserved registers will already have been restored by the kernel C functions, but Linux saves/restores all the registers anyway so debuggers (the `ptrace` system call) can modify that state all in one place.

Comment: reply to:`Of course, if this thrd_yield() function is ever called from an interrupt handler that might run when user-space has valuable state everywhere (pre-emptive multi-tasking), that's a whole different ball-game.`      In my toy os, the c `thrd_yield()` function is call by the appliction on it's own, not by the interrupt handler. Howerver the timer interrupt and timer isr does exist, in this case it will save all registers and switch context.

Comment: @untitled: Ok, then yeah, cooperative multi-tasking is easier, and does just look like a function call that eventually returns, from the PoV of the thread that's yielding.

Comment: Reply to: `Everything else is call clobbered, like RFLAGS, all the vector regs, AVX-512 mask regs, and x87 st0..7.`   What is different from call-clobbered and caller-save? Like RFLAGS, C program will never change direct flag, but other threads may be not written by C, it may written by assembly, so it may change any regs that can be changed by a user program.

Comment: @untitled: [call-clobbered is a more descriptive synonym for caller-save, aka volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078/224132). A function can expect a `call` instruction to leave all such registers modified, and can itself modify them.  If you have hand-written asm that calls `thrd_yield`, it should expect it to modify RFLAGS, and should have DF=0 before the call (DF=0 after the call).  Exactly like calling a compiler-generated function: assume it follows the x86-64 System V calling convention.

Comment: @untitled: The x86-64 SysV ABI does specify that DF=0 before every call, and DF=0 on return; I thought of that at one point while writing my answer, but forgot to mention it or figured it was covered by saying it's exactly like calling an ABI-compliant function.  If you want to let asm code be more sloppy, you could maybe include a `cld` in `thrd_yield` so it will always leave DF=0 regardless of the old state you're switching away from.

Comment: @untitled: Updated with some of what I wrote in comments, plus a mention of thread-local storage / FSGSBASE extension, and the AC flag.